Movie about a school taken hostage by tech savvy villains and saved by a teen guy
I  remember watching an English movie almost 7-8 years ago where the school gets taken hostage by a bunch of terrorists/mafia/just bad guys. The hero is a teen student. 
All I can recall is that the boy has a (step) sister (who he is not on that good terms with), I think, who is taken hostage along with another girl and a bunch of other kids (all rich kids for ransom) inside the school. The military cannot also get in due to the tech savvy villains. The kid sets traps along the school to sabotage the plans of villains. And while sitting on the roof of the school he communicates with his (step) parents who wait outside the school via a radio or a phone.
I keep recalling this movie sometimes but not the name. It's more of a kids movie and nothing gory. And I think it may be a late 90s English movie. I can't recall the actors, it's all a little hazy. 
Edit: It is not Toy Soldiers - this is more of a kids movie - euphoric vibes than action and stuff. Its Masterminds (1997) as answered.

Possible duplicate of 80s - 90s Movie about school siege

@Johnny OP has explicitly said it's not toy soldiers. No dupe.

At first glance this was most likely the 1991 movie Toy Soldiers. The terrorists take over the school and keep the military at bay, the students rebel violently, etc. A clone of Die Hard which basically created the lone hero v terrorist genre.
But further details show it is the clone of the clone, Masterminds from 1997. Patrick Stewart is the villain. The main character is forced to take his sister to her private school when hilarity ensues. A bit light hearted compared to Toy Soldiers, with the same general plot. Instead of an all boy boarding school, it's a general private school.

This school is not all male. The hero has a sister in the school (younger to him) and other girls and i'm very sure its not as violent as TS. Its not TS.. i came across this movie too while searching for the above movie. I will try and add some additional information if possible..

@Anu7 We appreciate you explaining why this movie isn't the right one, and offering to provide more information!

@anu7 found it.

Yes ! its that movie - masterminds ! thank you !! @Thunderforge  thank you :)
